# How do I Set data within a WCF Service from the hosting application?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, networking

I have a server application that must communicate with a separate server monitor application. The server monitor should display information to the user such as what clients are connected to the server.

My problem is that I cannot expose the server data to the WCF service for the server monitor to access. I know that I could use public methods on the WCF service and set it using some kind of password, but this seems like a really gross way to do it.

Is there a way to expose WCF service methods to only the hosting application so that I can set the available data? Failing that, is there any alternative way for me to achieve the desired results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Method Level Ssecurity protection. Code project has an example of how to go about this. Have a looksie [Service Method Level Security](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/318810/WCF-Service-Method-Level-Security-using-Message-Co)